# GNUradio : stream data using multiply_cc()

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I am using a USRP to transmit BPSK modulated data. To modulate, I use a 80 000 elements vector (*vector_source_c* format) which I want to multiply with the data (*vector_source_c* as well) I'd like to send.

My problem is that the data is important, so I'm trying to multiply it by slices with my vector, using the block **multiply_cc()**. I'm affraid the ultiplication is made only between my modulation vector and the 80000 first elements of my datam then repeated.

Is it how *multiply_cc()* works ? If true, is there a block I can use to multiply and stream ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. multiply_cc does exactly what the name suggests: it takes one item from both input streams and generates one output item, then the next, and so on.

Comment: I am affraid it could loop if one stream is smaller than the other and thus ignore the bigger stream. Is it possible ?

Comment: I don't understand that, either, sorry.

Comment: Sorry... If one stream is N bits and the other N x m bits = [N1, N2 ... Nm], and I try to multiply_cc() them, are we sure that the output won't be [N x N1 ... N x N1] instead of [N x N1 ... N x Nm] ?

Comment: by repeating each element of the first stream `m` times – that's what the *Repeat* block is for!

Comment: Oh, yes, thank you, I didn't think of that : this will remove the ambiguity on the multiplication

Comment: There's really no ambiguity at all!